# what does "The pure part of dimension $d -1$ of $D$" mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In A. Andreotti On to Theorem of Torelli American Journal of Mathematics Vol. 80, No. 4, pp. 801-828, it is written:

Let $ f: X \longrightarrow P $  be a rational
map of a projective irreducible variety of dimension $d$ on a projective space $P_d$.

Let $A$ be the set of points $y \in P$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ consists of $n$ distinct
points. The minimal algebraic variety containing the complement of $A$
(i. e. the closure of the complement of $A$) will be denoted by $D$.

The pure part of dimension $d -1$ of $D$ has an intrinsic meaning in terms of the extension $k(P)\subset k(X)$ and the chosen model $P$ of $k(P)$. It will be called the branch locus of the rational map $ f: X \longrightarrow P $.

My question is: what does "The pure part of dimension $d -1$ of $D$" mean?

Comment: It means the portion of $D$ consisting only of the points at which $D$ has dimension $d-1$.

Comment: What does it mean $ D $ have a dimension $ d-1 $ at a point?

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04MS

Comment: Your answer is good for me, because Definition 27.10.1 is for a scheme. And I already asked in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296797/morphism-of-projective-varieties-to-a-morphism-of-schemes  how I could see a relationship between schemes and projective varieties

Comment: In that Definition 27.10.1, can we think that scheme is projective variety? For after all, the morphism of the body of my question is of projective varieties.

Comment: Yes, certainly. Projective varieties embed fully faithfully into the category of all schemes.